# How likely is a total economic collapse due to the potential coronavirus impact?

Tags: stocks, debt, economics

Most signs show that lockdown could easily stretch through the summer. A freeze in consumer spending would cause multiple industries to fail causing a ripple effect.

To be specific, if lockdown lasts through the summer, and a second virus wave occurs in the fall as expected, then lockdowns will continue further into the year. The timeframe for a vaccine is 12-18 months earliest. Then, the vaccine must be manufactured and distributed. Since the virus is so widespread that it is now assumed that it will reach a global critical mass, this essentially guarantees the collapse of the restaurant, airline, tourism, and hotel industries as they cannot sustain prolonged losses in a capitalistic structure. If they fail, their suppliers fail, and so on. History has shown that large systems are prone to failure time and time again, esp. when accountability is obfuscated (e.g. the Titanic, the World Wars/Holocaust, and now this). In the past Egypt fell, and then Rome fell. What's to say our current systems won’t fail, even if as a slowly sinking ship?

EDIT: This question was closed, before I received enough good, thoughtful answers. As of tonight (April 4th) Bernie Sanders held a virtual address on the situation. He's looking at the unemployment projections that were posted by the St. Louis Fed's models and has spoken with a number of economists. Finally a voice of reason in this media circus. He has confirmed that a potential collapse is possible as another 47 million Americans may become jobless - this is unprecedented and would be absolutely devastating to American civilization.

Comment: by my calculations, it's possible that some places (e.g. NYC) may already be nearing saturation (given the number of asymptomatic cases), in which case any vaccination will be too late anyway, and many will recover without even knowing they had it.

Comment: Economics are off topic for this site. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Well, a system of reorganization in bankruptcy often just wipes out the shareholders and makes the bondholders the new shareholders. That's why I don't favor government bailouts because the purpose of the bailout is not to save the shareholders but just to give the bondholders time to hedge their bonds before reorganization.

But the economy can adapt to an 18 month time period of doing things differently. Unfortunately, many individuals are going to give up on seclusion and go out and catch the virus.

But how does the economy adapt? Young people work the positions that face the public. Factory workers wear protective clothing and equipment. People drink beer at home instead of at bars. Restaurants sell take-out roasts and casserole dishes. Stores have people wait in their cars until their number is called. Many people work or school from home.

Comment: Yes, and in fact one might consider this a transformative event as people discover new opportunities and ways of working which weren't obvious before.